# Inaccurate rotation of Aiming Dots that are supposed to represent trajectory of launch object

Tags: unity, c#

I am trying to create aiming dots that will help assist the player in launching the object is the desired direction. The Aiming dots are the white dots beside the character that are supposed to rotate in relation to where the phone's trajectory should go.

The problem is that there is a weird offset that happens when aiming I can't just add a number to fix it because this is circle type aiming system meaning radians and degrees are involved. For some reason, the rotation of the aiming dots which mimics the trajectory of the launch objects path is only usually near correct when its rotation of the aiming dots is around 350 degrees give or take.

Below is the relevant code and pictures.

```
    public class AimingDots : MonoBehaviour
    { 

        public ArmLauncher armLauncher;

        public float changingXAim;
        public float changingXAimUnRounded;

        public GameObject[] madeDots;

        //This is the gameobject of the Aiming Dots
        public GameObject fullDotObjects;

        // Start is called before the first frame update
        void Start()
        {
            armLauncher = FindObjectOfType<ArmLauncher>();
            madeDots = GameObject.FindGameObjectsWithTag("AimingDot");

            fullDotObjects = GameObject.Find("AimingDots");

            foreach (GameObject aimDot in madeDots)
            {
                aimDot.gameObject.SetActive(false);
            }
        }

        // Update is called once per frame
        void Update()
        {
            //The ChangingXAim's are all in collaboration to increase the length between dots and to display them when the player draws back their finger from the original touch point on the screen
            changingXAimUnRounded = armLauncher.changingX / 1400;
            changingXAim = Mathf.Round(armLauncher.changingX / 200);
            changingXAim = Mathf.Clamp(changingXAim, 0f, 9f);



            MakeDots();
            DotsBehavior();
            RotateDots();

            Debug.Log("Dot Rotation: " + fullDotObjects.transform.eulerAngles);
        }

        public void MakeDots()
        {
            if (changingXAim > 0.5f)
            {
                if (changingXAim >= 1 && changingXAim <= 1.9f)
                {
                    madeDots[0].gameObject.SetActive(false);
                    madeDots[1].gameObject.SetActive(false);
                    madeDots[2].gameObject.SetActive(false);
                    madeDots[3].gameObject.SetActive(false);
                    madeDots[4].gameObject.SetActive(false);
                    madeDots[5].gameObject.SetActive(false);
                    madeDots[6].gameObject.SetActive(false);
                }

                if (changingXAim >= 2 && changingXAim <= 2.9f)
                {
                    madeDots[0].gameObject.SetActive(true);
                    madeDots[1].gameObject.SetActive(false);
                    madeDots[2].gameObject.SetActive(false);
                    madeDots[3].gameObject.SetActive(false);
                    madeDots[4].gameObject.SetActive(false);
                    madeDots[5].gameObject.SetActive(false);
                    madeDots[6].gameObject.SetActive(false);
                }
                else if (changingXAim >= 3 && changingXAim <= 3.9f)
                {
                    madeDots[0].gameObject.SetActive(true);
                    madeDots[1].gameObject.SetActive(true);
                    madeDots[2].gameObject.SetActive(false);
                    madeDots[3].gameObject.SetActive(false);
                    madeDots[4].gameObject.SetActive(false);
                    madeDots[5].gameObject.SetActive(false);
                    madeDots[6].gameObject.SetActive(false);
                }
                else if (changingXAim >= 4 && changingXAim <= 4.9f)
                {
                    madeDots[0].gameObject.SetActive(true);
                    madeDots[1].gameObject.SetActive(true);
                    madeDots[2].gameObject.SetActive(true);
                    madeDots[3].gameObject.SetActive(false);
                    madeDots[4].gameObject.SetActive(false);
                    madeDots[5].gameObject.SetActive(false);
                    madeDots[6].gameObject.SetActive(false);
                }
                else if (changingXAim >= 5 && changingXAim <= 5.9f)
                {
                    madeDots[0].gameObject.SetActive(true);
                    madeDots[1].gameObject.SetActive(true);
                    madeDots[2].gameObject.SetActive(true);
                    madeDots[3].gameObject.SetActive(true);
                    madeDots[4].gameObject.SetActive(false);
                    madeDots[5].gameObject.SetActive(false);
                    madeDots[6].gameObject.SetActive(false);
                }
                else if (changingXAim >= 6 && changingXAim <= 6.9f)
                {
                    madeDots[0].gameObject.SetActive(true);
                    madeDots[1].gameObject.SetActive(true);
                    madeDots[2].gameObject.SetActive(true);
                    madeDots[3].gameObject.SetActive(true);
                    madeDots[4].gameObject.SetActive(true);
                    madeDots[5].gameObject.SetActive(false);
                    madeDots[6].gameObject.SetActive(false);
                }
                else if (changingXAim >= 7 && changingXAim <= 7.9f)
                {
                    madeDots[0].gameObject.SetActive(true);
                    madeDots[1].gameObject.SetActive(true);
                    madeDots[2].gameObject.SetActive(true);
                    madeDots[3].gameObject.SetActive(true);
                    madeDots[4].gameObject.SetActive(true);
                    madeDots[5].gameObject.SetActive(true);
                    madeDots[6].gameObject.SetActive(false);
                }
                else if (changingXAim >= 8 && changingXAim <= 9)
                {
                    madeDots[0].gameObject.SetActive(true);
                    madeDots[1].gameObject.SetActive(true);
                    madeDots[2].gameObject.SetActive(true);
                    madeDots[3].gameObject.SetActive(true);
                    madeDots[4].gameObject.SetActive(true);
                    madeDots[5].gameObject.SetActive(true);
                    madeDots[6].gameObject.SetActive(true);
                }
            }
        }

        public void DotsBehavior()
        {
            madeDots[0].gameObject.transform.localPosition = new Vector3(-2.47f, 0, 0);
            madeDots[1].gameObject.transform.localPosition = new Vector3(madeDots[0].gameObject.transform.localPosition.x - changingXAimUnRounded, 0, 0);
            madeDots[2].gameObject.transform.localPosition = new Vector3(madeDots[1].gameObject.transform.localPosition.x - changingXAimUnRounded, 0, 0);
            madeDots[3].gameObject.transform.localPosition = new Vector3(madeDots[2].gameObject.transform.localPosition.x - changingXAimUnRounded, 0, 0);
            madeDots[4].gameObject.transform.localPosition = new Vector3(madeDots[3].gameObject.transform.localPosition.x - changingXAimUnRounded, 0, 0);
            madeDots[5].gameObject.transform.localPosition = new Vector3(madeDots[4].gameObject.transform.localPosition.x - changingXAimUnRounded, 0, 0);
            madeDots[6].gameObject.transform.localPosition = new Vector3(madeDots[5].gameObject.transform.localPosition.x - changingXAimUnRounded, 0, 0);
        }

        public void RotateDots()
        {
            fullDotObjects.transform.eulerAngles = new Vector3(0, 0, -armLauncher.finalLaunch.y);
        }
    }
////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

    using System.Collections;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using UnityEngine;

    public class ArmLauncher : MonoBehaviour {

        //ArmLauncher is the class with the responsibility of launching the phone
        public bool startTracking;
        public bool preTracking = true;

        public GameObject throwingArmPiv;
        public GameObject phoneObject;
        public GameObject phoneLaunchPanel;
        public GameObject playerCharacter;
        public GameObject rotationManager;

        public float yStartValueLaunchAngle, yValueLaunchAngle = 0;
        public float xStartValueLauchPower, xValueLauchPower = 0;

        public Vector3 changingYLookArmRestricted;
        public Vector3 changingY;

        public float changingX;

        public Vector3 beforeTouchPosition, touchPosition;
        public Vector3 finalLaunch;

        void Awake()
        {
            startTracking = true;
        }

        // Use this for initialization
        void Start () {
            throwingArmPiv = GameObject.Find("ThrowingArmPiv");
            phoneLaunchPanel = GameObject.Find("PhoneLaunchPanel");
            rotationManager = GameObject.Find("RotationManager");
        }

        // Update is called once per frame
        void Update () {

            beforeTouchPosition = new Vector3(Input.mousePosition.x, Input.mousePosition.y, Input.mousePosition.z);
            touchPosition = Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint(beforeTouchPosition);

            playerCharacter = GameObject.Find("PlayerCharacter");
            StartTracking();

            Debug.Log("final lauch: " + finalLaunch);

        }

        public void BeginArmLaunch()
        {
            phoneObject = GameObject.Find("Phone");
            xStartValueLauchPower = Input.mousePosition.x;
            yStartValueLaunchAngle = Input.mousePosition.y;
            startTracking = true;
        }

        public void LaunchPhone()
        {
            phoneLaunchPanel.SetActive(false);

            startTracking = false;
            phoneObject.GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>().bodyType = RigidbodyType2D.Dynamic;
            phoneObject.GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>().mass = 10;

            phoneObject.transform.SetParent(null);

            phoneObject.GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>().velocity = finalLaunch;
            phoneObject.GetComponent<SpriteRenderer>().sortingOrder = 9;
        }

        public void StartTracking()
        {
            if (startTracking)
            {
                xValueLauchPower = Input.mousePosition.x;
                yValueLaunchAngle = Input.mousePosition.y;

                changingY = throwingArmPiv.transform.eulerAngles = new Vector3(0, 0, Mathf.Atan2((touchPosition.y - transform.position.y), (touchPosition.x - transform.position.x)) * Mathf.Rad2Deg);

                changingX = xValueLauchPower - xStartValueLauchPower;

                changingYLookArmRestricted = new Vector3(0, 0, Mathf.Clamp(changingY.z, 23.8f, 132f));

                throwingArmPiv.transform.eulerAngles = changingYLookArmRestricted;

                finalLaunch = new Vector3(-changingX / 4, -changingY.z, 0f);

                if (changingYLookArmRestricted.y <= 23.8f)
                {
                    rotationManager.transform.eulerAngles = changingY / 2.35f;
                }
                else if (changingYLookArmRestricted.y >= 132f)
                {
                    rotationManager.transform.eulerAngles = changingY / 4;
                }

            }
        }
    }
```

////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
[image: Example of it going wrong. You can see how it is slightly off when the rotation deviates from 350 this offset happens]

///////////////////////////////////////////////////////
[image: Example of when it goes right. For some reason its always around 350 of the Aiming dots that rotation is near correct]

//////////////////////////////////////////////////////
[image: Example of when it foes wrong again. It is slightly off when the rotation deviates from 350 this offset happens]

Comment: I'm working on an answer, but it's taken me half an hour just to puzzle out what's going on here. You have places where you're reading an angle in degrees and trying to use it as a units-per-second velocity or vice versa. Some bits work with input in pixels, others in world units. Some say the origin of the input is where the mouse was at the start, others say the origin is "this" transform's position. Some seem to want to use x input = power, y input = angle, other parts want to throw parallel to the dragged vector... which of these conflicting versions is what you actually want to do?

Comment: @DMGregory Please Tell me what's specifically confusing so that I can clarify in the question ie. variables and method functionality.

Comment: I list several specific issues above. But to finish an answer, what I really need is the intended aiming behaviour. Is the launch velocity supposed to be parallel to the drag of the mouse, or the line from "this" object to the mouse, or is the mouse movement meant to control power and angle on the x and y axes respectively, or some other mapping from input to velocity?

Comment: @DMGregory When the player lifts up the mouse the value is stored between the position in which he/she first had contact with the screen and when he/she let go. changingX is the power and changingY is Angle at which the object is shot.